# How to use node-expose-sspi windows authentication on NextJs

Tags: next.js, active-directory, ldap, middleware

I want to integrate my NextJS application with Windows Active Directory; I have searched a lot but didn't find good articles to explain that.

I tried to use the `node-expose-sspi` module but struggled with how to integrate it into the application.

In a normal express app the usage is like this:

```
const express = require("express")
const { sso } = require("node-expose-sspi")
app.use(sso.auth())

app.get('/sso', (req, res) => {  
console.log(req.sso)
  return res.end()
})
```

I couldn't get any success with API middleware; could anyone help with that, so I could be able to use it in my NextJS app without creating a custom server?

Also please let me know if there is a better way to integrate with active directory other than node-expose-sspi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to handle it like that:

```
const { sso } = require("node-expose-sspi")

const ssoAuth = sso.auth(ssoOptions)

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        try {
            return ssoAuth(req, res, () => {
                res.json({ sso: req.sso })
                resolve()
            })

        } catch (error) {
            reject(error)
        }
    })
}
```